# How to send GET values without redirecting user to that URL page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I want to send GET values to another script so that the script takes those GET values and create a PDF as per it and sends to the user email. I just need how can I send GET values in URL using JavaScript without redirecting to the URL you send GET values with.

If anyone can help me here using JavaScript or jQuery. It will be a great help.

This is the button. It's not a form.

```
<a href="javascript:" id="wpe_btnOrder" class="btn btn-wide btn-primary" data-tldinit="true"><span class="fa fa-check" data-tldinit="true"></span>SEND ME THE PDF<canvas class="lfb_shineCanvas" data-tldinit="true" width="202" height="41" style="border-radius: 4px;"></canvas></a>
```

This is how I want to send the values:

> https://scripts.google.com/?name=name

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: You need to simply do an [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) request for this to work.

Comment: `$.get('your_function.php', {'var':'value'}, function() {});` - simplest form of get call using jQuery

Comment: @ACD Does it redirect the page to your_function.php?

Comment: @DineshKumar it won't

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "your url",
  type: "get", //send it through get method
  data: { 
    name: "put the name value here", 
  },
  success: function(response) {
    //Do Something
  },
  error: function(xhr) {
    //Do Something to handle error
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest form of get call using jQuery

```
$.get('your_function.php', {'var':'value'}, function() {});
```

Comment: Facing the no access control allow origin header absent